# Clarify on Lemma 1.2.2, Hovey's Model Categories

Tags: category-theory, homotopy-theory, model-categories

Let $\mathscr C$ be a model category, and denote as usual by $\operatorname{Ho}\mathscr C$ the localization of $\scr C$ with respect to the weak equivalences.

For any category $\scr D$, let $\mathrm{Fun}'(\mathscr C,\mathscr D)$ be the class of functors $\scr C\to D$ sending weak equivalences to isomorphisms. The property defining $\operatorname{Ho}\mathscr C$ is the following: $$ (*)\ \ \mathrm{Fun}(\operatorname{Ho}\mathscr C,\mathscr D)\cong \mathrm{Fun}'(\mathscr C,\mathscr D)$$ naturally in $\scr D$. Lemma 1.2.2 (iii) on Hovey's *Model Categories* says that, viewing $\mathrm{Fun}'(\mathscr C,\mathscr D)$, $\mathrm{Fun}(\operatorname{Ho}\mathscr C,\mathscr D)$ as categories instead of mere classes, the bijection ($*$) extends to an isomorphism of categories.

It is easy to see this when $\operatorname{Ho}\mathscr C$ is constructed as a quotient of the free category over $\scr C$, but I don't know how to prove it just by using the universal property of $\operatorname{Ho}\mathscr C$: I obtain a functor $\mathrm{Fun}(\operatorname{Ho}\mathscr C,\mathscr D)\to \mathrm{Fun}'(\mathscr C,\mathscr D)$, bijective on objects of course, which I can't show to be isomorphic. However, the universal property should contain all the information about $\operatorname{Ho}\mathscr C$; is there a way to prove Lemma 1.2.2 (iii) only by the universal property, or maybe, the fact that we are dealing with $2$-categorical structure in some way, requires to choose a certain representation for $\operatorname{Ho}\mathscr C$? Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the following facts:

- For every category $\mathcal{D}$, we have a natural isomorphism
  $$\textrm{Fun} (\operatorname{Ho} \mathcal{C}, [\mathbf{2}, \mathcal{D}]) \cong \operatorname{mor} {[\operatorname{Ho} \mathcal{C}, \mathcal{D}]}$$
  where $[-, -]$ is the functor category.
- For every category $\mathcal{D}$, we have a natural isomorphism
  $$\textrm{Fun}' (\mathcal{C}, [\mathbf{2}, \mathcal{D}]) \cong \operatorname{mor} {[\mathcal{C}, \mathcal{D}]_\mathrm{h}}$$
  where $[-, -]_\mathrm{h}$ is the full subcategory of functors sending weak equivalences to isomorphisms.

It is then a formal consequence that the natural bijection
$$\textrm{Fun} (\operatorname{Ho} \mathcal{C}, \mathcal{D}) \cong \textrm{Fun}' (\mathcal{C}, \mathcal{D})$$
can be promoted to a natural isomorphism
$$[\operatorname{Ho} \mathcal{C}, \mathcal{D}] \cong [\mathcal{C}, \mathcal{D}]_\mathrm{h}$$
as claimed.

Comment: Thanks! I think that your argument is clear, just two questions. (1) Do you confirm that your argument only proves that there is a bijection $mor([C,D])\cong mor([C,D]_h)$, and it is necessary to check that such bijection  actually extends (to a functor) the bijection we already have on objects? (Which anyway should be clear as the bijection $Fun  (\operatorname{Ho} C, [2,D])\to Fun (C,[2,D])$ is defined by precomposition with $C\to \operatorname {Ho}C$)

Comment: (2) This proof seems to use only the universal property of $\operatorname {Ho}C$ (the classical one, not the $2$-categorical version if there is one); so is the first period of the other answer not correct? Or maybe I'm making confusion. Thanks again

Comment: Well, yes, you need to know that the two bijections do actually come from a functor. But as you say it is more or less clear. The real point is that naturality in $\mathcal{D}$ means we can choose $\mathcal{D}$ to extract not just the objects but also the morphisms and even arbitrary diagrams in the functor category.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that you can deduce the isomorphism of categories
$$\operatorname{Fun}(\operatorname{ho}\mathcal{C},\mathcal{D}) \cong \operatorname{Fun}'(\mathcal{C},\mathcal{D})$$
just knowing the isomorphism of classes $$\operatorname{Ob Fun}(\operatorname{ho}\mathcal{C},\mathcal{D}) \cong \operatorname{Ob Fun}'(\mathcal{C,D})$$
since taking objects is not a conservative functor. If you have an explicit construction of $\operatorname{ho}\mathcal{C}$, however, you can use it to prove the isomorphism of categories and deduce from it the isomorphism of the level of object classes.

You are right that a good universal property should give you all the information about an object, but the point here is that by taking $\operatorname{Ob}$ you truncate the universal property, so you lose information...

Comment: Thank you, but there is still something unclear: what do you mean when you say that the information given by the universal property is truncated by restricting to the objects (of the functor categories)? The statement of the property involves only the objects (i.e. the functors), not also the natural transformations. Are you talking about a $2$-categorical version of the universal property maybe?

Comment: Well, you were asking, whether the isomorphism of categories (2-categorical universal property) follows from the isomorphism of classes (1-categorical universal property). I don't think so. But of cause the 1-categorical UP follows from the 2-categorical one. And you need a concrete construction to prove the 2-categorical one.